# Why Float is not instance of the Monoid type class?

Tags: haskell, monoids

My question is why Float is not readily defined to be an instance of the Monoid type class ?
I mean what is against it ? Doesn't Floats have the *identity element* and if no why? Also the operations `(*)` and `(+)` are associative in the set of Floats, or ?

Comment: Well the question actually already partially contains the answer: what operation will you pick? There is no inherent better one. `Monoid` is defined for types where it makes sense to have a straight forward "correct" operation.

Comment: So because you could pick `(*)` and `(+)` as operation for it, it makes no sense ? Excuse me but I kinda don't really understand the problem

Comment: @IPirro: the problem is that you can only define *one* instance per type. So if you pick `(+)`, you cannot pick `(*)` and vice versa. In mathematics, a monoid is a 3-tuple: `(S,+,e)` with `S` the set, `+` the operation, and `e` the identity. But there can be multiple monoids with the same set, operation and/or identity element.

Comment: Ok so just to be correct, Integer and Double wouldn't also not be instances of the Monoid class ?
Oh alright that explanation is good

Comment: based on the query `:i Monoid`, I get that `[a]`, `Ordering`, `Maybe a`, and `a -> b` are monoids (as well as tuples given the elements of the tuples are monoids). So indeed, `Integer` is not a monoid.

Comment: @IPiiro: It's the same as with _Int_ or _Integer_. The reasons why _Int_ has no default Monoid instance is mentioned in every tutorial on Monoids.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which monoid is are you talking about? Sum? Product?

These are already available by wrapping the type with the `newtype` `Sum` or `Product`. But you are correct that addition and multiplication are not associative for floating-point numbers. That's somewhat a different issue, however. The issue is that there's not an obvious "correct" monoid to choose by default.

Comment: I know addition isn't associative for floating-point. Why isn't multiplication? Something about normalization or NaN?

Comment: @dfeuer Consider something like `(x*y)*(1/y)`, compared to `x*(y*(1/y))`, where `x*y` is too large to fit in a float (ie, evaluates to Infinity). After you get to Infinity, dividing by y no longer gets you back to x. There are probably similar issues when `x*y` is simply large enough to lose the precision that `x` alone had, so that when you divide by `y` again you can't get back all the information `x` had, even though you land in the same neighborhood.

Comment: @dfeuer: Also, rounding will cause `x*(y*z) != (x*y)*z`.

Comment: I want to emphasize that the decision not to give the numeric types `Monoid` instances is extremely subjective. The haskell ecosystem is by no means consistent if the rule is "only obviously correct instances, else newtype wrapper" `Maybe` and lists for instance both have equally obvious alternatives for instance.

Comment: @jberryman: I can understand Maybe but lists are basically the free monoid for sets to begin with.